# Repeating AJAX function after computer sleeps

Tags: ajax, web, model-view-controller, visual-web-developer

I have a webpage (developed in MVC) where once loaded it calls an AJAX function that hits a controller action that returns a partialview. This is then used to refresh the 'dashboard', wait 5 seconds and then it calls the same function again. It is essentially just continually updating the home page with up to date information.

If the computer lid is closed or sleeps, this stops. I was wondering if the computer was used again, if this automated function could restart? I notice that if I open my computer and go back to Facebook, it seems to refresh it self and show me new notifications so it seems possible?